# asp.net mails suddenly stop working. How I can debug my asp.net mvc 4 app for the issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

In my asp.net mvc 4 website I wrote a function (using try catch c#). This function work fine till yesterday.

I have test it now and it's not work. I debug it and their is no exception made in try catch when I debug my code.

I think no exception means it will work. I don't have information about server. The smtp I got is work fine till yesterday.

I tried to make testing in my computer or on live website. None of them send the mail.

Now someone tell me how to fix this.

```
   public static bool SendMail(string EmailID, string subject, string message, string senderMail, List<string> AttachFiles)
        {
            try
            {
               // code here work before but now.
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I debug it and found nothing. do someone know how to find the issue when nothing exception made here?

Comment: are you get `false` when you call `SendMail` ?

Answer (score 0):

But how are you sending this mail? VIa a local SMTP server? via a remote smtp server? Can you log into the SMTP server and send mail - are you sure it's not the SMTP Server itself that is having problems? What happens if you use your email client to send via this SMTP server - does it work?

One thing you can do is setup your mail code to not send directly via SMTP but to use a Pickup directory instead; that way you can be sure that your code is doing its job (it will create the email in a folder instead of sending it via SMTP). Once you know that works, then you can be sure that the problem is the SMTP server.

Also you should post the code that isn't working as expected, otherwise it's all guesswork on our part.

Comment: We have Dedicate Server which use IIS to host apps.I got the email address and password to set in web.config. I do it and it's work till now. I use system.net.mail and use server smtp settting which make it work when I debug it on localhost or run it online. Now none of them work nor make exception.

Comment: ok so are you using the SMTP virtual server that ships with IIS? Have you checked the BadMail/Queue directory to make sure that the emails are not being created correctly but not sent for some other reason?